# How to store a List of @Embedded objects in GAE-JDO?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, data-modeling, jdo

I am trying to store a List of embedded objects in GAE/JDO.  I am getting a Datanucleus exception:

> Field "Product.shippingOptions" is of type "java.util.List" yet has been specified as embedded. DataNucleus doesn't support embedding of this type. Your embedded type must be PersistenceCapable.

Here's a simplified version of my classes:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType=IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable="true")
public class Product
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy=IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY) 
    private Long id;

    @Persistent(defaultFetchGroup = "true")
    @Embedded
    private List<ShippingOption> shippingOptions;
}

@PersistenceCapable
@EmbeddedOnly
public class ShippingOption
{
    @Persistent
    private String shippingType;

    @Persistent
    private int price;

    @Persistent
    private String currency;
}
```

I don't want to use a separate table/kind to store the shipping options for every product, because the shipping option also needs to be stored with the Order object when that is created.

Is there a way to store a list of child objects in GAE/JDO?  If not, what is the "correct" way to model this data in GAE/JDO?

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in GAE/J docs does it say that they support storing a Collection of embeddable objects; simply because there are no such things as *join tables* where that would be stored in GAE/J. Think about where you think it ought to store those elements. If you mean in the same table as the owner, then that is why you have @Serialized.

PS You do not need @Persistent on those fields; they default to persistent for all of the main types.

Comment: Yes, I expect the collection of embeddable objects to be stored in the owner's table.  How do I use @Serialized?  Do I need to serialize the List of child objects and store it as a Blob in the owner's table?

Comment: Nice of someone to downvote my answer. Perhaps they could also point out what they though was such a problem with this answer and then I could attempt to correct it, just a thought. Or maybe someone has a hidden agenda here? work for Oracle maybe?